# How to select in jQuery siblings without going on a lower level

Tags: jquery, structure, siblings

How can i get the siblings of a sepcific element (in that case the PLACEHOLDER element) without going deeper in the structure?
I tried $("#PLACEHOLDER").siblings() but that gets me the C and D li elements too. I need a way to get just the siblings on exact that level (Here A, B and E).

```
<section id="root">
    <ol class="sortable">
        <li id="A"><div>A</div></li>
        <li id="B"><div>B</div>
            <ol>
                <li id="C"><div>C</div></li>
                <li id="D"><div>D</div></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li id="E"><div>E</div></li>
        <li id="PLACEHOLDER"><div>PLACEHOLDER</div></li>
    </ol>
</section>
```

Comment: you are missing a whole bunch of closing `</li>`s in your code... Which is why probably the html police isn't too happy and returns you things you don't want

Comment: Just copied the code wrong to the question, end tags are there. The problem too.

Answer (score 0):

If you select `$('#PLACEHOLDER').siblings().andSelf()` it should give you `#A`, `#B` and `#E` and `#PLACEHOLDER` only.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5aFHQ/).

The reason why your `siblings()` call may have gotten you the `#C` and `#D` elements is because perhaps your base selector was `.sortable li`  when it should have been `.sortable > li`.

Comment: Nope, if i place try to select C or D, it gives me just the elements on that level. But above it gives me all elements.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand that. Where i have to apply that kind of selector?

Comment: @Sandro That has not selected the other `li` elements, it's just the `background-color: red` property on the parent elements. That's why I used a `border` instead in my example.

Comment: Ok, are you sure? Check and run this http://jsfiddle.net/5aFHQ/8/ . What i need specifically is to get the element above the placeholder element, but on the same level. In that case i would need something that gives me E

Comment: Yes he is correct, you didn't specify background to use for C and D, and by default it is transparent. Hence why they are red as well. See http://jsfiddle.net/5aFHQ/10/

Answer (score 0):

`$('#PLACEHOLDER').siblings()` works perfectly well and gets only A, B and E as Alex pointed out its just the background color of the parent take a look here.

http://jsfiddle.net/d4udts/W9cCE/1/

If you want to select a sibling above the placeholder you can do this

```
$('#PLACEHOLDER').prev();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d4udts/W9cCE/2/

It gives you exactly the previous sibling alone and if u want all the previous siblings u can use `prevAll()`

http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/5aFHQ/11/
```

`.text()` function returns all text inside selector, so your code returns also C and D. Get the children element of selector and after that call `.text()`